# ORA-01017 when connect with Pentaho PDI

Tags: oracle, express, pentaho, pdi, ora-01017

I installed XE 18c and I have my connections with SQL Developer.
I created a connection with Pentaho PDI, but I have this error:

```
Error connecting to database [Localhost] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)
ORA-01017: nom utilisateur/mot de passe non valide ; connexion refusée
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)
ORA-01017: nom utilisateur/mot de passe non valide ; connexion refusée
```

I add to C:\app\myuser\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\sqlnet.ora this lines:

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8
```

I add to C:...\PDI\data-integration\lib this files:

```
ojdbc6.jar; ojdbc7.jar; ojdbc8.jar
```

In the connection, I changed my database name from ***XE*** to ***/XE***

Always this error.

Answer (score 1):

ORA-01017 means exactly what it says. Invalid userid or password. Oracle is too dumb to lie about that one.  Your request actually reached an oracle database (perhaps not the one you think) and that database rejected your username and/or password. It has nothing to do with sqlnet settings or jar files.  It's a bad username/password, pure and simple. Have you checked password case sensitivity?  Does your password have a special character (like "@") that gets interpreted by some intermediate process?  For example, when connecting with sqlplus at a command line, the '@' is interpreted as the indicator that the connect string follows.  So a command 'sqlplus myuser/P@ssword' is interpreted as using a password of 'P', and a tns connect string of 'ssword'.